# capture() method works incorrect in casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

The casperjs captures a part of window. it happens when I make screenshot while testing in casperj. I use

```
this.capture('google.png', {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 1280,
    height: 960
});
```

I also tried use

```
this.capture('google.png');
```

and

```
this.captureSelector('weather.png', '#body');
```

How can I make a screenshot of the whole window (document) ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, try setting a `viewport`:

```
var casper = require('casper').create ({
  waitTimeout: 15000,
  stepTimeout: 15000,
  verbose: true,
  viewportSize: {
    width: 1280,
    height: 960
  },
  pageSettings: {
    "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1262.0 Safari/537.10',
    "webSecurityEnabled": false,
    "ignoreSslErrors": true
  },
  onWaitTimeout: function() {
      // casper.capture('./out/wait-timeout:_' + TimeTidy() + '.png');
      // throw new Error stuff;
  },
  onStepTimeout: function() {
      // casper.capture('./out/step-timeout' + TimeTidy() + '.png');
      // throw new Error stuff;
  }
});
```

And then use:

```
casper.capture('google.png');
// or if within casper block:
// this.capture('google.png');
```